# Twitch get access token

Tags: php, twitch

I'm using the following PHP class which I found on GitHub: [Twitch oauth class](https://github.com/Xxplosions/twitchtv-oauth/blob/master/twitchtv.php)

So I've been creating the Authentification site, which will let you authentificate your twitch account and redirect you to another site using the following url:

```
http://website.com/twitch/dashboard.php?code=xxxxxxx&scope=user_read+channel_read+chat_login+user_follows_edit+channel_editor+channel_commercial+channel_check_subscription
```

Now I've used the following code to receive the `access_token`:

```
<?php
   $ttv_code = $_GET['code'];
   $access_token = $twitchtv->get_access_token($ttv_code);
   $user_name = $twitchtv->authenticated_user($access_token);

   if(isset($user_name)) {
      echo 'Thank you ' . $user_name . '!  Authentication Completed!';
   }else{
      echo 'Authentification failed!';
   }
?>
```

But sadly there's no response coming back from the function. The function looks like the following:

```
function get_access_token($code) {
    $ch = curl_init($this->base_url . "oauth2/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $fields = array(
        'client_id' => $this->client_id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client_secret,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri' => $this->redirect_url,
        'code' => $code
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $data     = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($data, true);
    return $response["access_token"];
}
```

Does anyone have a idea what causes this mistake? I would appreciate any kind of help.